# Frames are not working properly in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently working on some legacy project.

I've got an HTML-file which contains a `<frameset>` with a bunch of `<frame>` elements.
My task was to inject a js-script into this html to add a sidebar and header with some styles. I did a bunch of manipulations with frames, resizing it to make my sidebar and header fit. So far i've been testing it in Google Chrome and it worked just fine. Once i finished next step was to test it in other browsers and it just did not work anywhere. (My interest so far is in IE and FF, so i tested there).

To specify what's not working: My new sidebar and header is fine, fully rendered, but all the frames are not visible. They exists in the DOM but any size of any frame is 0 width.
Initial html works just fine in every browser.

I guess the problem is with resizing the frames, but im struggling to find any solution or even cases like mine. Maybe im missing something big about the frames.

Initial document frameset is like this:

```
<FRAMESET  rows="32px,*">
    // here is some frames
</FRAMESET>
```

With a js inject i rebuild this html to this:

```
<body> 
  <div id='main'> 
    <div id='main_menu'> //menu
    </div>
    <div id='main_frameset'>
     <frameset cols="81px,*" border="0" framespacing="0">
      <frame></frame>
      <FRAMESET  rows="32px,*"> <-- Initial frameset
      </FRAMESET>
     </frameset>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Framesets and frames are deprecated for a long time ago, you should not use them anymore. You're also misusing the frameset, on a frameset page the body tag is not allowed.

Comment: @Teemu, I know its deprecated, but its a legacy project i cant do anything with it.
Can be the body tag be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Most likely yes. The frameset page is kind of a head section for the pages shown in the frames, it's not purposed to show any additional elements. Frameset was dropped when HTML5 was introduced, it's hard to even find a proper documentation of it nowadays (even from MDN). I'd suggest you to drop the frameset tag and replace the frames with `iframe`s. Usually the most of the old frameset scripts will work also with iframes.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp have you set you doc type to legacy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.
Thanks to [@Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu).

If somebody meet something like i did the best solution is to wrap your deprecated part in `<iframe>` element. In my case it transformed my DOM to this:

```
   <div id='main_frameset'>
    <iframe>
    <#document>
     <head></head>
     <frameset cols="81px,*" border="0" framespacing="0"> <-- Previous wrap
       <frame></frame>
       <FRAMESET  rows="32px,*"> <-- Initial frameset
       </FRAMESET>
     </frameset>
    </#document>
    </iframe>
    </div>
```

By default this `iframe` element will be 300x150 with border and scrolls (both horizontal and vertical) on. I added some properties:

- `scrolling="no"` - disable scrollings.
- `frameborder="0"` - disable border.
- `width="100%"` (Not style.width, just width).
- `height="100%"`(Not style.height, just height).

Width did fine, it stretched out `iframe` to full remaining space, but height, for some reason didnt want to work (still was 150px). After some time i understood that this properties position themselves to the parent element. So i added `height: calc(100vh - @myHeaderHeight)` to the parent `<div id='main_frameset'>` and everything settled well.

Another issue was to write my previous html into the `iframe`. You have to access inner document with `iframe.contentWindow.document` property only by using `onload` event. This is the way to prevent case when its not fully loaded at the time you try to modify it. Accidentally, iframes' body has default margin, so i recommend reset it 0 too. In my case i fully replaced `<body>` with `<frameset>` to prevent further issues like initial.

I hope nobody will ever need to read this answer and wont use anything that is so outdated.

Answer (score 0):

An HTML document with a `<frameset>` has it **instead of** a `<body>`. It isn't an element you can drop in anyway (that's an `<iframe>`).

If you want to add a new sidebar and header, add them as frames.